# How similar is print command in R to printf in C

Tags: r

How similar is print command in R to printf in C? I want to write a command printf(%s, variable) in R? Any suggestions how to do that?

My code:

```
v <- "abc"
print(sprintf(%s, v)
```

Error: unexpected input in "print(sprintf(%s, v)"

Comment: You need to put the %s in inverted commas as "%s", similar to format specifiers for printf in C. And also dont forget to close the bracket.

Comment: There's a `formatC`function. But I do not know what the `printf` function provides so no comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

```
R> v <- "abc"
R> print(sprintf("%s", v))
[1] "abc"
```

The first was to not write the format string as a string in quotes. The second was a missing closing parenthesis.

But you probably want this as an argument to `cat()` where you want to end a newline in one of two places:

```
R> cat(sprintf("%s", v), "\n")
abc 
R> cat(sprintf("%s\n", v))
abc
R>
```